# Cuando un usuario se registre o identifique una vez completada la acción la página debe mostrar la última página que el usuario se encontraba

Tags: java, jsp

¿Como puedo lograr eso,  en java en JEE ?

@Override
protected String getSuccessRedirect(final HttpServletRequest request,
final HttpServletResponse response) {
if (httpSessionRequestCache.getRequest(request, response) != null) {
return httpSessionRequestCache.getRequest(request, response)
.getRedirectUrl();
}

```
    return "/";
}
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta?

Comment: Hola, amigo te recomiendo que pases por aquí: [tour] y que te leas estos artículos: [help/dont-ask], [help/on-topic], [help/behavior] y que arregles tu pregunta mirando este articulo: [mcve] tambien puedes pedir ayuda en: [chat]